# Add instruction to PE executable

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have win app exe file developed using VB.NET 2010, I need to add message box to the beginning of the file, so the message box appears when the exe is executed.

Is it possible to add this instruction to a compiled and built exe file?

Comment: Do you own the application? If yes then decompiling it and changing the code is a lot easier. If not then you can create a `startup` script (like through powershell) that can show the message box before launching the application. Please provide more details on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options:

- Just open the original project, add the messagebox before the main form is shown, recompile and deploy.
- If you don't have access to the original source, create a "launcher" executable that displays the messagebox and then executes the original executable.
- Decompile the executable, add the messagebox code, recompile.
- Go fiddle with the bits in the executable. But don't.

Comment: I don't have the source code of the app. But need to amend the exe itself, the idea is, I need to develop a tool to add message box to the beginning of existing exe file without the source code, just amending the exe itself; Is that possible?

Comment: Please refere to the following url: http://www2.inf.h-brs.de/~ikarim2s/how2injectcode/code_inject.html

Comment: @Abusnake That is a very interesting link.